# MS Visio 2016. Как показать Member (Inner) Class в UML диаграмме

Tags: классы, uml, inner, visio

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.
           К сожалению, поиски не дали результатов,
коннектора со значком "+" в Visio 2016 нет!

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, в MS Visio 2016 это делается с помощью соединения называемого композиция:
[image: Соединение композиция в Visio 2016]

А такой вариант генерирует плагин simpleUML для IntelliJ IDEA:
[image: Сгенерировано плагином simpleUML для IntelliJ IDEA]

Именно его я и пытался повторить в Visio.
                                             Теперь хорошо бы узнать почему такие разные стандарты диаграмм используются.